# PHP Repeating Results in Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, repeat

Hello guys so I have this simple problem and I need help solving it. I am creating a simple PHP shortcode for WordPress where it takes 3 inputs `audio` `text` and `totalposts`. I was able to create the layout of the shortcode but I dont know why but its repeating the results in while loop.

Below is the code:

```
function header_custom_box($atts) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'audio' => '', 'text' => '', 'totalposts' => '3'), $atts, 'header-custom-box' );

    $audioFiles = explode( ",", $atts['audio'] ); 
    $descText = explode( ",", $atts['text'] );

    $postCount = $atts['totalposts'];
    $posts = array();
    $audioArray = array();
    $imagesArray = array();
    $textArray = array();
    $buf = '';
    $counter = 0;

    foreach ($audioFiles as $audioFile) {
        $attr = array(
        'src'      => $audioFile,
        'loop'     => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'preload' => 'none'
        );
        $audioArray[] = wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
    }

    foreach ($descText as $desc) {
        $textArray[]  = $desc;
    }

    while ($counter < $postCount) { 
        $buf .= '<div class="header-tab-box">';
        $buf .= '<div class="audio-text"><h2>Your Daily Audio:</h2> <br/>';
        $buf .= $textArray[$counter];
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $buf .= '<div class="audio-player">';
        $buf .= $audioArray[$counter];
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $posts[$counter] = $buf;
        $counter++;
    }
    return $posts;

}
add_shortcode( 'header-custom-box', 'header_custom_box' );
```

Also, it displays result when I `var_dump($posts)` but if I `return $post` it says `Array`

There is one more thing I need to apply in this shortcode, which is `delay` in every post, like it should change to the next post after every 24 to 58 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before your while loop, do a ``print_r($textArray);`` and ``print_r($audioArray);``. See what is in the arrays. Your while loop looks fine  so my guess is that you have the content repeating in the arrays.

Comment: Do you really want to keep adding to `$buf` the whole time, or should it be blanked at the start of the `while()` loop?

Comment: Already did that mate, its working fine. For the inputs as "One,two,three" the $textArray outputs `array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" }`

Comment: @TZHX No `$buf` is working like a simple holder which temporarily holds a post and then moves it onto the `$posts` array.

Comment: @Fahad Yes -- but you don't clear it, you're just adding to it the whole time so for the second one, it contains the values for the first and second, for the third it has the first, second and third...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's repeating because you don't reset your `$buf` variable in each iteration
so in first iteration `$buf = "firstRow"`, second iteration `$buf = "firstRowSecondRow"`... And this prints you Array, because you returns array `$posts` contains pieces of html. If You want to print all pieces together just use `implode` function

```
 while ($counter < $postCount) { 
        $buf = ""; // make this empty in each iteration
        $buf .= '<div class="header-tab-box">';
        $buf .= '<div class="audio-text"><h2>Your Daily Audio:</h2> <br/>';
        $buf .= $textArray[$counter];
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $buf .= '<div class="audio-player">';
        $buf .= $audioArray[$counter];
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $buf .= '</div>';
        $posts[$counter] = $buf;
        $counter++;
    }
    return implode('',$posts);
```

Comment: Yea, you're right, that's the issue. So how do I reset $buf after every entry?

Comment: I added one row in your loop `$buf=''`; you got this in my code

Comment: Oh, okay let me check

Comment: @FahadSohail this part of your question actually i don't uderstand :) what is that delay, how should it work?